# Change FILE TYPE to File uploaded date and time - PHP

Tags: php, upload

can you help me with this php script? It is working well yet i want to change the filetype to the time when the file is uploaded to the database or just add the filetime without deleting the filetype. Please and Thank You :)

**UPLOAD.PHP**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB


    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='downloadreports.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='homepage.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why dont you just use timestamp in the database?

Comment: good point yet having trouble in putting up a code for it.